# Slick2D ComponentListener added to MouseOverArea not responding to right mouse clicks

Tags: java, slick

I am developing a UI using Slick2D and experimenting with MouseOverArea.  I have noticed that if I add a ComponentListener to my Button (which extends MouseOverArea) it only responds to left-clicks on my mouse, but not right-clicks.  The MouseOverArea itself responds to both.  If I call notifylisteners() in my Button subclass then ComponentListener does respond to right-clicks, but it gets called twice for left-clicks.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?  Code included below:

```
package slick2dbutton;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.AbstractComponent;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.ComponentListener;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.GUIContext;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.MouseOverArea;

public class Slick2DButton extends BasicGame {

    Button button;

    public Slick2DButton(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppGameContainer game;
        try {
            game = new AppGameContainer(new Slick2DButton("Slick2DButton Test"));
            game.setMaximumLogicUpdateInterval(60);
            game.setDisplayMode(640, 480, false);
            game.setTargetFrameRate(60);
            game.setAlwaysRender(true);
            game.setVSync(true);
            game.setShowFPS(false);
            game.start();
        } catch (SlickException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Slick2DButton.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
        button = new Button(container, new Image("res/bunsen burner #1.png"), 50, 50, new Slick2DButton.Listener());
        button.setMouseOverImage(new Image("res/bunsen burner #2.png"));
        button.inputStarted();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        button.render(container, g);
    }

    public class Listener implements ComponentListener {

        @Override
        public void componentActivated(AbstractComponent source) {
            System.out.println("Source: " + source);
        }
    }

    public class Button extends MouseOverArea {

        public Button(GUIContext container, Image im, int x, int y, ComponentListener listener) {
            super(container, im, x, y, listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(int button, int mx, int my) {
            super.mousePressed(button, mx, my);
//            this.notifyListeners();
            System.out.println("Button: " + button);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around my problem by re-writing my code to remove ComponentListener.  Doing this I got a single response to a left-click (or right-click).  This doesn't differentiate between left or right-clicks - it just picks up clicks, but that works for me.  My test code is posted below.

```
package testslick2dbutton;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.GUIContext;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.MouseOverArea;

public class Slick2DButton extends BasicGame {

    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    public Slick2DButton(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppGameContainer game;
        try {
            game = new AppGameContainer(new Slick2DButton("Slick2DButton Test"));
            game.setMaximumLogicUpdateInterval(60);
            game.setDisplayMode(640, 480, false);
            game.setTargetFrameRate(60);
            game.setAlwaysRender(true);
            game.setVSync(true);
            game.setShowFPS(false);
            game.start();
        } catch (SlickException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Slick2DButton.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
        button1 = new Button(container, new Image("res/Launch Normal.png"), 50, 50);
        button1.setMouseDownImage(new Image("res/Launch Press.png"));
        button1.setMouseOverImage(new Image("res/Launch Over.png"));
        button1.inputStarted();

        button2 = new Button(container, new Image("res/Launch Normal.png"), 200, 50);
        button2.setMouseDownImage(new Image("res/Launch Press.png"));
        button2.setMouseOverImage(new Image("res/Launch Over.png"));
        button2.inputStarted();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        button1.render(container, g);
        button2.render(container, g);
    }

    public class Button extends MouseOverArea {

        public Button(GUIContext container, Image im, int x, int y) {
            super(container, im, x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(int button, int mx, int my) {
            super.mousePressed(button, mx, my);
            if (this.isMouseOver()) {
                if (this == button1) {
                    System.out.println("Screen Button 1 Pressed!");
                }
                if (this == button2) {
                    System.out.println("Screen Button 2 Pressed!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the AbstractComponent section of slick has some problems. I am quite sure there are some bugs and so I stopped using it. The rest of the slick framework seems to work fine though.

Try alternatives like Nifty GUI which is compatible with slick

Comment: I'd forgotten about this question so thanks for coming back to me.  I re-wrote my code so that it didn't use AbstractComponent or ComponenListener and that worked for me - I get a single click for left clicks.  It doesn't differentiate for right-clicks, but I don't use them in my app so it doesn't matter.  I did try Nifty at the time, but wasn't keen on it for some reason.  Can't remember why though!  I'll post my test programme in case anyone else is still trying to use Slick2D.